# Pandas matching algorithm with itself

Tags: pandas, algorithm

I'm trying to create a matching algo in pandas that does the following with a given table:

A table contains purchases and sales of products by date, item, quantity (+ for purchases and - for sales) and price.

Conditions:

- Create an algorithm that matches purchases and sales per item and the corresponding average profit for each item in total.
- Matches can only be on the same date, otherwise they are not matched at all.
- Remaining positive or negative inventories per day are ignored
- Negative inventories are allowed.

Example with a single product:

```
date   product    quantity    price
1      X          +2          1
1      X          -1          2
1      X          -2          4
2      X          +1          1
2      X          +1          2
3      X          -1          4
```

Answer:
The result would be that only on day 1 the 3 trades are matched, with a profit of -2+2+4=4. Because inventory is +2, -1, and then again -1. The remaining inventory of -1 is ignored. Day 2 and 3 have no matches because the trades are not closed on the same day.

Correct output:

```
product   Profit 
X         +4
```

Is there any elegant way to get to this result without having to loop over the table multiple times with iterrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reproducing the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'product': ['X']*6,'quantity':[2,-1,-2,1,1,-1],'price':[1,2,4,1,2,4]})
```

The process that you describing could use groupby & aggregate, something like this:

```
df.groupby('date').sum()
```

But I don't fully understand your rules for matching. So in Day 1, I got a different total profit. Price * quantity is (+2*1)+(-1*2)+(-2*4)=-8, so profit seems to be 8.

Using iterrow() is a rather bad practice. Not only you're writing excessive code, but also it's likely much slower [(check a comparison here)](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06).

Most of those type of jobs can be accomplished by combining groupby(), aggregate() and apply(). Check out [this great tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-groupby-aggregate-transform-filter-c95ba3444bbb).

I hope this helps you or future answers :)